# How to use fftw3 on Qt?

Tags: qt, fftw, mingw32, cimg

Im making an aplication for image filtering and Im sucesfully using the CImg.h library to help with the task, but as you might know the fft isn't for any image and I need to activate the use of the fftw3 library to overcome this. And I dont have any clues on how to do that (I'm super new with Qt), if it helps somehow to the explanation I was able to do that on ZinjaI but for this new aplication I had to move to Qt to get a more friendly GUI.
Im using Qt 5.0.2 (32 bits) / Qt creator 2.7.0 on windows with minGW.
Thanks a lot for taking the time to read it and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Extra: Not as important as the other but if I also can learn how to avoid having the cmd.exe windows poping in front of my GUI would be cool :) (I guess the CImg.h functions make it pop, but not sure)

Comment: FFTW3 has nothing to do with Qt.  Have you read the tutorial? http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Tutorial.html

Comment: I use the Cimg.h library in my c code to do some image filtering tecniques, but CImg.h does only calculate fft for images on sizes of 2 (256,512,1024,...) then I have to configure CImg to calculate the fft (img of any size) with fftw3 which i was able to do in Zinja (saving the includes, lib and bin of fftw on the respective folders of the minGW zinjai was using and adding a line to the CImg.h) but giving my need of a GUI program i was trying to use the adventages of Qt in that regard but i wasn't able to configure Cimg to use the fftw on my Qt program (It's not like i did on zinjai)